# Application_Start does not respond to RegisterAllAreas()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, application-start

I'm new on MVC Application, please help me.

I have an Application on Visual Studio 2012 using Framework 4.0 on a Windows 7 pc and I'm debugging in IIS Express.

Starting debugging, my application doesn't respond: after starting `Application_Start` in the `Global.asax` file, execution doesn't goes on and the browser get no answer or error message from the server (that is my `localhost`).

When `Application_Start` is executed run to the instruction `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` and no more.
Debug doesn't stop, but neither goes to the following instruction:

```
Sub Application_Start()
    Try
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()             ' regularly executed
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()     ' Break point: goes here and no more
        .............
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorString As String = ex.Message  ' never goes here
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have really few area to registrate.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Federico

**PS.:
I resolved it**, but I still can't understand the reason of my error.

I simply wrote the instruction `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()` immediatly after `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()`.
Now my code is:

```
Sub Application_Start()
    Try
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()
        ..........
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim errorString As String = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

And it works.

Still, I have a lot of problem using Hub for SignalR similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179644/signalr-connection-is-undefined) (but none of all suggested solutions works for me).
Have I to execute `MapHubs` always as the first instruction of `Application_Start`?
Thanks!

Federico

Comment: You only have to call MapHubs() before you register routes.  I usually call it right before any calls to IgnoreRoute() or MapRoute().

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you do have to MapHubs before you register other routes.

As for the debug stop not being hit, it's probably because you generally can't debug stop inside Application_Start. [More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641148/application-start-not-firing)